# "ActiveX component can't create object" in Access 2000 VBA app

Tags: ms-access, vba, recordset

I've got a VBA application that throws an "ActiveX component can't create object" exception when trying to run.

[image]

The breakpoint is set on the line that throws the exception:

[image]

I'm assuming that it has something to do with Me.Recordset (Me being the Access form).  The recordset is probably related to the Microsoft DAO Library, which is referenced.  Here are the current references:

[image]

The application is running on a Windows 98 machine, and the Access .mdb allegedly ran fine before (noone remembers what other computer it was originally on or the configuration of it.  The form itself just scrolls through records of data (which works fine), but when firing the above Calc_Confidence_Level() subroutine, it tosses an error on the recordset that I thought would be the same one that it was scrolling through.

Does anyone know what's going wrong here?  Even a push in the right direct to be able to debug this better would be great, as I don't exactly work with VBA/Access very often.

Thanks!

---

### Update 1

I looked in "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\DAO\" and don't see a .dll at all, only a .tlb file.  There should be a .dll in there, right?

[image]

Comment: Have you made sure that all referenced components are correctly registered using regsvr32.exe?

Comment: What data type is `Me.Recordset`? Put the cursor on `Recordset` (on the line having breakpoint), right click, goto definition to see how it is declared.

Comment: @shahkalpesh: Goto definition gives "Identifier under cursor is not recognized".  O_O

Comment: @0xA3: Check my update.  It was registered, but the actual .dll is missing. Now I just need to find where I can get that .dll.  Maybe it's on the Access install disk or downloadable.

Comment: @David: It's currently running in Access 2000, but I'm not sure what version of Access it was originally created in.

Comment: The references pretty clearly indicate that it started life in Access 2 or before, though it has also definitely gone through the conversion to Access95/97 (the DAO 2.5 compatibility library shows that). You need to get rid of as many of those references as possible. The VBA, Access and DAO references are the ones you should aim for as the minimum. Excel can be automated with late binding. OLE Automation is one of the default references from A2000 on, but it is almost entirely useless. Whether you need both DAO and ADO is up to you to determine, but I'd never have an ADO reference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make clear if (1) you have an active recordset in your form, and then (2) if your recordset is an ADODB one, or a DAO one. Usually, when a form is open the standard way (with a 'recordsource' property referring to a local\linked table or view), the recordset is of the DAO type. In these conditions, you need the DAO library.  If there is no 'recordsource' property for the form, there is no recordset, or it has to be set 'on the fly', for example in the 'on open' event. You then have to check what kind of recordset is declared in the proc. ('findfirst' is a DAO method, that cannot be used with ADODB recordsets)

Another thing could be to make sure that the form is not corrupted: open a new\empty database, import all objects from your active database, and test it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference 'Microsoft DAO x.x Object Library'.  You only have the DAO compatibility library referenced.

Comment: I added the Microsoft DAO 3.51 Object Library instead of the Compatibility Library, but get the same error.  If I try to add both, I get a naming conflict, so I have to use one or the other, but both give the same result.